# why is css not loading my background image in Github pages

Tags: css

I have tried  numerous solutions to this problem, yet nothing worked for me.
My image is in the root folder, same as css file and all of the other files.

```css
body{
background: url(data.jpg);
}
```

github link https://github.com/annaesma/annaesma.github.io

Comment: Your css doesn't contain `url(data.jpg)`, it contains `url(../data.jpg)`.

Comment: Welcome Esma! In order to help we need as much information as possible. For example, what is the actual URL/path for the image you're trying to use? The more info the better!

Comment: Just change path in your style to ./data.jpg and it will work :)

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line https://github.com/annaesma/annaesma.github.io/blob/master/main_1.css#L7
contains `../data.jpg` which means go back one directory (`../`).

remove `../` or replace it with `./` which means current directory.